# C# Handling Response Exception within ContinueWith Task (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, httpwebresponse

I hope everyone's doing well.

So we were tasked with using a method of multi-threading to run a GetResponse method.

```
WebResponse response = await Task.Run(() => request.GetResponse())
```

This works perfectly with the rest of my program.

**Now**, the issue takes place when I type a web address which is non existent and an exception occurs.

I've been trying to figure out a good way to catch this exception and add it to the label, but I have been unable to do so.

```
WebResponse response = await Task.Run(() => request.GetResponse())
            .ContinueWith(
            ex =>
            {
                if (ex.Exception != null)
                    ex.Exception.Handle(x =>
                    {
                        Label1.Text = (x.Response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode;
                        return true;
                    });
            });
```

In this code snippet, I can't figure out how to catch the exception that is thrown. (Exception could be 404 error, or other)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: Wrap the await in a try catch and then handle the exception as necessary.

Comment: What is the idea behind the combination of `await` and `ContinueWith`? Why not just await? Or better, use HttpClient with native async/await support.

Answer (score 0):

Get your exceptions like below

```
 List<Exception> Exceptions = ex.Exception.InnerExceptions.ToList();
```

and loop through them to find the task exceptions